# mongo query is hanging in filter of mono

Tags: reactive-programming, spring-webflux, spring-data-mongodb

I am facing mongo reactive repository hanging issue which cause the whole application hanging.

```java
shipment.getItems().forEach(item -> {
    return deliveryRepository.findById(item.getDeliveryNumber())
        .filter(delivery -> Objects.isNull(delivery.getState()) || !delivery.getState().equals(TrackObjectState.DELIVERED))
        .filter(delivery -> deliveryStatusShouldBeUpdatedToDelivered(delivery, shipment, gamMessage))
        .flatMap(delivery -> {
            delivery.setState(TrackObjectState.DELIVERED);
            return deliveryRepository.save(delivery);
        }).subscribe(delivery -> log.info("delivery: " + delivery.getDeliveryNumber() + " is updated to state delivered"));
});
```

inside method deliveryStatusShouldBeUpdatedToDelivered, I called a another service named incotermLocationService via blow code.

```java
var alternativeLocations = incotermLocationService.getAlternativeUnLocationCodesByUnlocationCode(destinationLocation).blockOptional();
```

and this incotermLocationService code as following.

```java
public Mono<Set<String>> getAlternativeUnLocationCodesByUnlocationCode(String unlocationCode) {
    if (log.isDebugEnabled()) {
        log.debug("alternative location get by un-location code is called with un-location code: " + unlocationCode);
    }
    
    return incotermLocationRepository.getAlternativeLocationsByUnLocationCode(unlocationCode)
        .flatMap(incotermLocation -> Flux.fromIterable(incotermLocation.getUnLocationCodes()))
        .map( unloCode -> { log.debug("unlocationCode: " +  unloCode + " is returned"); return unloCode;})
        .collect(Collectors.toSet());
}
```

but this incotermLocationRepository.getAlternativeLocationsByUnLocationCode() was in hanging for ever.
I checked this method which was called in other place works well. Then I take it out from the filter.

```java
shipment.getItems().forEach(item -> {
    var deliveryOptional = deliveryRepository.findById(item.getDeliveryNumber())
        .filter(delivery -> Objects.isNull(delivery.getState()) || !delivery.getState().equals(TrackObjectState.DELIVERED))
        .blockOptional();
    
    if (deliveryOptional.isPresent() && deliveryStatusShouldBeUpdatedToDelivered(deliveryOptional.get(), shipment, gamMessage)) {
        var delivery = deliveryOptional.get();
        deliveryOptional.get().setState(TrackObjectState.DELIVERED);
        deliveryRepository.save(delivery).subscribe(savedDelivery -> log.info("delivery: " + delivery.getDeliveryNumber() + " is updated to state delivered"));
    }
});
```

Then repository was called and the whole logic works as expected.
Did u face this before that a reactive repository used in a filter method never triggered even it is called with block?

Comment: A reactive process should be a whole, but you break this line which can cause unexpected errors. You mustn't use any blocker method like "blockOptional". (Allowed for test cases, but not in main code.) If you would like async process, you need Sinks. (https://prateek-ashtikar512.medium.com/projectreactor-sinks-bac6c88e5e69) I will never use a direct subscription if you do not unsubscribe from it, as it can result in a memory leak. An exception for Beans because they are permanent.

Comment: hi, thanks for your reply. In this case, to change delivery state, i must first check it should be changed or not. Hence a block was used. Is there any alternative to do that in async? BTW, The link you provided can not be open.